# How to use a color scale in a power bi donut chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data looks something like this:

```
|Animal  | Viewes |
|Cat     | 7      |
|Chicken | 12     |
|Cow     | 17     |
|Dog     | 28     |
|Goat    | 36     |
```

But there can be an unknown numer of other animals and the Views usualy don't add up to 100 like this example.
My donut cart chooses the colors randomly.
[image]

Since I do not know what animals will apear in the future I do not want to make a Measure like:
*If Animal equals Goat then gren...*

My goal ist something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to just choose one color like violet and let it get darker and darker the smaler the number of Views gets?
Or to create some kind of measure that calculates the color code dependeing on the sorting order of the number of Views?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible now. You just have to build a **bar chart** then on the columns of the chart you can set the colors by using the `fx` button.
[image]

Then you can use the format painter to tranfer the colors from bar-chart to the pie-chart.
[image]
This will apply the color scale on pie-charts.

Comment: Nifty trick, nice!